# reference member of a strange C++ struct

Tags: c++, struct, reference, unions

I came across a library called PolyBoolean. This is essentially irrelevant to my question. 
In the library there is a strange struct type as follows:

```
struct VNODE2
{
    VNODE2 * next;
    VNODE2 * prev;
    UINT32   Flags;
    union
    {
        VECT2 p;
        GRID2 g;
    };
};
```

and GRID2 is defined as:

```
struct GRID2
{
    INT32 x, y;
};
```

The `GRID2` defines a point, `VECT2` is another representation of a point similar to `GRID2` and `VNODE2` is a `node`. Say I have a `VNODE2` structure variable `v2`, how can I get the value of `x` and `y` in `g`?

I tried `v2.g.x`, the vs2008 compiler gave me an error: `"error C2059: syntax error"`  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry for the bad structure of the code posted. I am new here, didn't know how to format it as it is in an editor

Comment: This is exactly why users with a high enough reputation can edit other people's posts. :)

Comment: @liudaisuda For the record, when creating a question, there's a preview of the question below the text entry area.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code sample? Or at least the definition of `v2` which you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is anonymous union, so you refer to members just as they are, see:
[image]

be sure that you declared GRID2 before your struct. Here is working example. You can also name your union to create instance in your class.

```
typedef int UINT32;
typedef int VECT2;
typedef int INT32;

struct GRID2
{
    INT32 x, y;
};

struct VNODE2
{
    VNODE2 * next;
    VNODE2 * prev;
    UINT32   Flags;
    union
    {
        VECT2 p;
        GRID2 g;
    };
}; 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    VNODE2 v;
    v.g.x=1;
    return 0;
}
```

in case if you would like your union to have name do it as follows:

```
struct GRID2
{
    INT32 x, y;
};

struct VNODE2
{
    VNODE2 * next;
    VNODE2 * prev;
    UINT32   Flags;
    union
    {
        VECT2 p;
        GRID2 g;
    }myNamedUnion;
}; 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    VNODE2 v;
    v.myNamedUnion.g.x=1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

v2.p and v2.g should work.

```
struct VNODE2
{
  VNODE2 * next;
  VNODE2 * prev;
  union
  {
    int p;
    float g;
  };
}; 

int main()
{
  VNODE2 bla;
  bla.p = 17;
  std::cout << bla.p << std::endl;
  bla.g = 18;
  std::cout << bla.g << std::endl;
}
```

output:

> 17
>
> 18

Comment: 1. The question is about accessing the members of `p` and `g`. 2. I don't like invoking UB and saying it "works" (setting `g` then reading `p`).

Comment: Oh, I thought he just wanted to access the items in the union. Also good point that this is UB! Is it always UB if you use a union in different ways or would it be okay to write bla.p and then output that?

Comment: @Sarien It's UB if you set one member of a union and then read another, unless they are both standard-layout structs which share a prefix and you only access that prefix.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification. I fixed it in the example.